# Problem related to an mathematical operation applied to the cardinal it’s of a set.

Tags: set-theory, induction, contest-math, problem-solving

Consider a positive integer $a > 1$. If $a$ is not a perfect square then at the next move we add $3$ to it and if it is a perfect square we take the square root of it. Define the trajectory of a number $a$ as the set obtained by performing this operation on $a$. For example the cardinality of $3$ is $\{3, 6, 9\}$.
Find all $n$ such that the cardinality of $n$ is finite.

The following part problems may attract partial credit.

$\textbf{(a)}$Show that the cardinality of the trajectory of a number cannot be $1$ or $2$.

$\textbf{(b)}$Show that $\{3, 6, 9\}$ is the only trajectory with cardinality $3$.

$\textbf{(c)}$ Show that there for all $k \geq 3$, there exists a number such that the cardinality
of its trajectory is $k$.

$\textbf{(d)}$ Give an example of a number with cardinality of trajectory as infinity.

**Note:**In the following following problem I have tried to find the cases for the given options and prove the general case with induction but no possible idea came to my mind . It will be very nice if a rigorous answer is provided to all the given questions of the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the operator that you are proposing. Is the 3 in {3,6,9} there because the set contains the starting point, or because 3 happens to be the square root of 9? Is {4,2} A valid trajectory for n = 4? If so, then (a) is false. It is true that no trajectory can have cardinality {1}, since at a minimum the set contains some n and the sqrt(n), and the only number that is it's own square root is 1. (b) is false if ( I interpret the Operator Correctly) As, {13,16,4} is the trajectory for n = 13. (c) I have to think about. (d) The trajectory of 2 never terminates.

Comment: Proof of (d) (RAA) Let 2+3n be a perfect square for some natural number n. As every perfect square is of the form 3k or 3k+1 for some integer k, we consider two cases. Case 1: 2+3n = 3k, 3(n-k) = -2, (n-k) = -2/3... a contradiction as n,k are both integers, n-k is also an integer. Case 2: 2+3n = 3k+1, (n-k) = -1/3 which is a contradiction, as n-k is an integer.Thus, 2+3n is never a perfect square, and as 2 itself isn't a perfect square. The trajectory of 2 never terminates.

Comment: You should show how far you have reached in your attempts, at least for some of the sub questions.